# Vector iterator

Tags: pointers, vector, iterator

I have

```
class CBase
{
.......
};

class CDerived : public CBase
{
......
};

vector<CBase*> mpBase;
vector<CDerived*>::iterator InfoIt;

InfoIt=mpBase.begin();
```

VC++ 2008 generates error C2679. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's not legal. You need to use an iterator that's of the same type as the vector. If the vector really contains pointers to CDerived objects, make it `vector<CDerived*>`. If it doesn't, you'll need to try downcasting the objects in the vector, which, of course, may not succeed. You may want to look into `dynamic_cast` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Not all CBase*s are CDerived*s. Say there are other classes derived from CBase.  Then what does it mean to interpret CDerived2* as a CDerived*? What does it mean to interpret a CBase* as a CDerived*? It is possible to put both of those types in a CBase vector.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a simple pointer object; `CDerived* foo = (CDerived*)*(mpBase.begin());`. But like the others have said, that may not always be possible.